# Screen issue after update

Tags: 14.04, updates, xubuntu, screen, virtualization

New to Linux. I'm running XUbuntu 14.04 on a VM. There is no issue before update but after updating via software updater and rebooting, this happens:

[image]

The right area of the screen is not clickable but whatever I open on the left part again appears on the right. Another thing I noticed is that while booting, there is a grey screen for a few seconds but the desktop appears. I could see several questions regarding grey screen but I'm not sure whether any of them are relevant for this.

Please let me know if this is a known issue and if there is any way I can revert to he original desktop before upgrade. (and apologies in advance if this question is already asked)

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me as well in both Xubuntu 14.04 LTS and Lubuntu 14.04 LTS running on VMware player 3.1.4 build-385536. It seems a kernel issue that is not yet sorted out.

I sorted out the problem by downgrading the kernel.
Check kernel version (in my case it was 3.13.0-37-generic)

```
    uname-r
    3.13.0-37-generic
```

Remove it and update grub

```
    sudo apt-get remove 3.13.0-37-generic
    sudo update-grub
    sudo shutdown -r now
```

This reverted to kernel 3.13.0.24-generic that does not exhibit the issue.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Did you install the VMware guest additions? If so, then I think you did not have the `dkms` package installed at the time you ran  the VMware installer. This causes the guest additions to be installed only for the current kernel and any updates will require you to reinstall the VMware additions. Install `dkms` and check with `dkms status` for the status of the VMware guest additions installation overview per kernel update installed.